# Makefile in osX

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, makefile, nuke

The following code is NUKE plugin makefile. (Mirrior.cpp -> Mirrior.dylib)

I just want to add "header.h" and "header.cpp" in my makefile.

Where should I change it????

```
# Compiler Info ('g++-4.0 --version')
# i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.0.1 (GCC) 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5494)
# Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
# This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
# warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
# End Compiler Info Output
NDKDIR ?= /Applications/Nuke8.0v2/Nuke8.0v2.app/Contents/MacOS
MYCXX ?= g++-4.0
LINK ?= g++-4.0
CXXFLAGS ?= -g -c -DUSE_GLEW -I$(NDKDIR)/include -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch x86_64
LINKFLAGS ?= -L$(NDKDIR) -Wl,-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch x86_64
LIBS ?= -lDDImage -lGLEW
LINKFLAGS += -bundle
FRAMEWORKS ?= -framework QuartzCore -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation -framework Carbon -framework ApplicationServices -framework OpenGL -framework AGL 

all: Mirror.dylib 

.PRECIOUS : %.os

%.os: %.cpp
    $(MYCXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(@) $<
%.dylib: %.os
    $(LINK) $(LINKFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(FRAMEWORKS) -o $(@) $<

clean:
    rm -rf *.os Mirror.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous, but I think this will do what you want:

```
Mirrior.dylib: header.os

%.dylib: %.os
    $(LINK) $(LINKFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(FRAMEWORKS) -o $(@) $^
```